# Help with MySQL getting count of a column with distinct another column?

Tags: php, mysql, count, distinct

Hi I want to get the count of column called 'response'. But even though a user submits many responses I want it to be only considered as one. So basically I want to get the count of 'response' with DISTINCT user_id. How can I do this? Thank you.

Comment: Can you describe an a little more detail about how your table is structured? What is your table called? Which field is the PK? Which fields are nullable?

Comment: Also you still have not responded to my questions to your previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680356/mysql-how-to-select-friends-from-a-friendship-table You will get much better answers if you answer the questions from those people who are trying to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure I understand your table structure, but maybe you want this?

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT userid)
FROM Table1
WHERE response IS NOT NULL
```

Result:

```
2
```

Test data:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (userid INT NOT NULL, response NVARCHAR(100) NULL);
INSERT INTO table1 (userid, response) VALUES
(1, NULL),
(1, 'a'),
(1, 'b'),
(2, NULL),
(3, 'c');
```

Note: if the response column cannot be NULL, you don't need the `WHERE response IS NOT NULL` clause.

Comment: Actually the answer I'm looking for is 1. i.e even though user has responded 3 times, I'm taking it as 1 in my system. Also what I need is not the count of userid,  the count of responses. Hope you understood. Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: @Thomas Puthoor: In my test data there are three different users and three responses, two of which come from the same user. So as I understand your requirements the answer should be 2, not 1.

Comment: Yes sorry my mistake. Thanks for your response. Sorry for taking your time.