# friendship database schema

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I'm creating a db schema that involves users that can be friends, and I was wondering what is the best way to model the ability for these users to have friendships. Should it be its own table that simply has two columns that each represents a user? Thanks!

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/1731/5880

Answer (score 58, accepted):

```
create table 
friendship(
user bigint, 
friend bigint,
primary key(user, friend),
key(friend, user),
constraint `fk_user` foreign key (user) references user(id),
constraint `fk_friend` foreign key (friend) references user(id)
);
```

When user 1 sends a friendship request to user 2, do

```
insert into friendship (user, friend) values (1,2);
```

If user 2 denies the request,

```
delete from friendship where user = 1 and friend = 2;
```

if user 2 accepts it:

```
insert into friendship (user, friend) values (2,1);
```

Then, a friendship can be found this way:

```
select f1.* 
from friendship f1
inner join friendship f2 on f1.user = f2.friend and f1.friend = f2.user;
```

You can make a view with this last query, it will help you query-ing for users' friends, or even friends of friends.

Comment: +1 for this straight and detailed answer. However, I try to balance pros and cons for one row vs. two rows per friendship. Could you explain why two rows are better in your opinion?

Comment: Good question. I use the above structure in a legacy application, but if I was to implement one, I'd give it a try with one-row structure.

If you have `user`, `friend` and `status` columns for a friendship (where status could mean pending, accepted, rejected or deleted), it would be a lot easier to query for pending requests (with two-rows you need a left join).
However, querying for an user's friends would be more difficult:
`select case when user=@userId then friend else user end as friendId
from friendship where (user=@userId or friend=@userId) and status = 1;`

Comment: First thanks to ceteras for the detailed explanation. On the topic: I would try with a mixture of these 2 methods. I would use the 2 rows approach, but for convenience I will add a 3-th row which will flag approved or pending request and when I insert a confirmation I will update the first row as well with flag approved.

Comment: why did you add columns both primary and key?

Comment: key(friend, user) was initially key(friend), but then later I made it a covering index so the ids could be retrieved straight from the index, without reading the table. The primary key wouldn't cover queries by friend column.

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure that, this is the way I would want to model the whole set up. When a user A sends request to user B, in my opinion, pending_friendship is created. 
When user B accepts this request, a friendship between the two is established. Usually this would be a two way relationship and would be great. But I would want to ensure that there is scope for a one way relationship in future. So I would model the scenario by making use of two tables for the relationship and one table for the user himself.

User(
user_id,
email,
password_hash,
name,
...,
...
)

pending_friendship(
user_id_from,
user_id_to
)

friendship(
friendship_id,
current_user_id,
friend_user_id,
is_following boolean # This would ensure scope for one way relationship.
)

Now lets look up the use cases-
1- **User A sends a request to user B-** I would create an entry in the pending_friendship table.
When user B wants to see which friend requests are pending, we can just do a select query based on friend_request_to column.

2- **User B accepts the friend request-** The pending_friendship item is deleted from the table. Two entries are made in the friendship table for the two sided relationship. Both users would follow each other.

3- **User B is a friend and does not want to follow user A's feed-** The is_following column is set to false for user B's friendship row of user A.

4- **User A does not want to be friends anymore with B-**(After all B has unfollowed him in case 3 :-) ) We go ahead and remove the two rows for friendship between the two users.

This schema does have more complexity but adds more clarity. It also allows you to have relationship of following a user.

Comment: and it can be achieved with a single table

Comment: True. I realized that later. A single table would suffice as well.
I think the single table would have the advantage of ease of schema and this has the advantage of having clarity. I guess it would depend on the designer as to what choice *he makes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes (use a n:m link table).

You have two entities:

- user (for User-Data like ID, Name, email etc.)
- relationship (links two users by ID)

create one table each.