# SQL Request : Display people who are not friend

Tags: mysql

i m trying to implement an "Add Friend" page, but i cant figure it what is the correct SQL to display for a user all the people he can add. Here are my tables :

**users**:

-id

-name

**friendship**

-id_user

-id_friend

This is the same kind of database of this post : [friendship database schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2910134/friendship-database-schema)

For a user i want to have all the users who are not friend with him, who havent asked him to be friend and who havent been asked to be friend with him

Edit :
This is the closest of the result i want, i have tried :

```
SELECT *
FROM user user
LEFT JOIN friend friend ON user.id=friend.id
WHERE friend.id IS NULL AND friend.id_friend IS NULL
```

But it just return all the people who havent got any friend.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Show us what you tried

Comment: Done. I tried many things, but none where concluant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[sqlFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b9d40/1/2) based on your `friendship schema` explained in the other linked question.

```
/* --------------get users who are not friends with 'Tim' */
SELECT u2.id,u2.name
FROM users u1,users u2
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1
                 FROM friendship f
                 WHERE f.id_user = u1.id AND
                       f.id_friend = u2.id)
  AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1
                 FROM friendship f
                 WHERE f.id_user = u2.id AND
                       f.id_friend = u1.id)
AND u1.id != u2.id
AND u1.id = 1;

/* ---------------get users who have not asked 'Tim' to be a friend*/
SELECT u2.id,u2.name
FROM users u1,users u2
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1
                 FROM friendship f
                 WHERE f.id_user = u2.id AND
                       f.id_friend = u1.id)
AND u1.id != u2.id
AND u1.id = 1;

/*  ------------- get users who have not been asked by 'Tim' to be a friend */
SELECT u2.id,u2.name
FROM users u1,users u2
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1
                 FROM friendship f
                 WHERE f.id_user = u1.id AND
                       f.id_friend = u2.id)
AND u1.id != u2.id
AND u1.id = 1;
```

all three queries have been set to search for data based on `Tim` with `u1.id = 1`, just change the last condition to whatever user id you're looking for.

the first query can be combined into an `OR` condition like below

```
/* get users who are not friends with 'Tim' */
SELECT u2.id,u2.name
FROM users u1,users u2
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1
                 FROM friendship f
                 WHERE (f.id_user = u1.id AND
                        f.id_friend = u2.id)
                     OR(f.id_user = u2.id AND
                        f.id_friend = u1.id))
AND u1.id != u2.id
AND u1.id = 1;
```

Left join solution [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b9d40/7/2) (you'll have to replace where the comparisons of ids of `1` to the user id of your choice, they occur  3 times in the first query, and twice in the second and third query)

```
/* get users who are not friends with 'Tim' */
SELECT u.id,u.name
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN friendship f ON
  (u.id=f.id_user AND f.id_friend = 1)
OR(u.id=f.id_friend AND f.id_user = 1)
WHERE
    f.id_friend IS NULL
AND u.id != 1;

/* get users who have not asked 'Tim' to be a friend */
SELECT u.id,u.name
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN friendship f ON
  (u.id=f.id_user AND f.id_friend = 1)
WHERE
    f.id_friend IS NULL
AND u.id != 1;

/* get users who have not been asked by 'Tim' to be a friend */
SELECT u.id,u.name
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN friendship f ON
  (u.id=f.id_friend AND f.id_user = 1)
WHERE
    f.id_friend IS NULL
AND u.id != 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

> not friend with him

This should do it:

```
SELECT *
FROM users U
WHERE NOT id IN (
  SELECT F.id_friend
  FROM friendship F
  WHERE U.id = F.id_friend
    AND F.id_user = 1
)
AND id != 1
```

Or

```
SELECT U.*, F.*
FROM users U
LEFT JOIN friendship F
  ON U.id = F.id_friend
  AND F.id_user = 1
WHERE F.id_user IS NULL
  AND U.id != 1
```

However,

> who havent asked him to be friend and who havent been asked to be friend with him

You do not have this information available in your schema.

EDIT: Too early :/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it return only people who don't have any friend. Where should i put the condition about a given user to show the people he his not friend with?