# Sequelize.js Create a friendship between 2 users

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

I have 2 models

**User**

```
module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
var User = sequelize.define('User', {
    email: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        validate: {
            isEmail: true
        }
    }
}, {
    classMethods: {
        associate: function (models) {
            User.hasMany(models.User, {as: 'Friends', through: models.Friendship});
        }
    },
    updatedAt: false
});

return User;};
```

**Friendship**

```
module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
var Friendship = sequelize.define('Friendship', {
    accepted: {
        type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
        defaultValue: false,
        allowNull: false
    }
}, {
});

return Friendship;};
```

As you see user has many users as friends and this creates the following table:

```
**Friends**
PK user_id
PK friends_id
   accepted
```

Now I have user Bob with id 1 and user Alice with id 2.

If I do

```
bob.addFriend(alice);
```

Which creates the following row in Friends table

```
user_id = 1
friends_id = 2
accepted = false
```

But when I do

```
alice.hasFriend(bob);
```

I get false because there is no row with (user_id = 2 && friends_id = 1).

How I can create a friendship like relationship between users so I that Bob could befriend Alice, but Alice would have to confirm that they are indeed friends?

I could have two rows with accepted status like: (1,2, true) and (2,1, false), when Bob befriends Alice, but I don't know how then display Bobs friends? The fact that Bob befriended Alice, does not mean she accepted his friend request. And for every Bob's friend, I'll have to check the other side (i.e. is X accepted the friendship from Bob) to make sure that Bob and X are indeed friends.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you against 2 rows in general or do you just don't want to create the datasets every time on your own? I'm still thinking about this behavior. I'm not 100% sure if this is a bug or intended.

Comment: @sdepold Thanks for the effort to help! I've updated the last paragraph of the question. I just don't know how to create a friendship relationship with "pending" status, i.e. if Bob sends friend request to Alice, Alice needs to confirm that they are friends, but since alice.hasFriend(bob) returns false, I'm stuck. Without ORM I would implement hasFriends for alice as a JOIN with where (user_id = bob.id AND friends_id = alice.id) OR (user_id = alice.id and friends_id = bob.id), this will cover both sides and give all scenarios where alice initiated the friendship and when alice was befriended.

Comment: And no, I don't think its a bug. The associations works correctly, its just a missing functionality / feature.

Comment: This is not a bug actually. You might want to look into contacts relationship or design :)

Comment: @majimboo do you mean something specific or is there a general approach to such problems?

Comment: @skwee357 there is a general approach. I actually am currently using it on my project. Something like facebook's friendship system right?

Comment: @majimboo yes, similar to Facebook. Thanks I'll google for contacts relationship

Comment: @skwee357 first off, this is more a database design problem at first. So try checking [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2910134/friendship-database-schema).

I personally use only 1 row per relationship, like `user1, user2, status`. if the status is pending then user2 still has not accepted the request.

Comment: @majimboo that's nice, but the problem here is also how do I implement such design with ORM like sequelize

Comment: Well, I have used sequelizejs before and I think you should really make a method to handle this instead of just using a relationship.

Comment: @majimboo, I see what you say. So instead of the general hasFriend and addFriend created by sequelize, I should implement my own methods. This is the solution I'm leaning towards, I just really hoped there is an option to do it in sequelize somehow but maybe such things are beyond the responsibilities of ORMs

Comment: @sdepold @majimboo Ok, I've tried many things, and I still can not reach the desired behavior. I tried to add class methods to Friendship model to check if A is friends with B like this `where: ['(user_id = ? AND friends_id = ?) OR (user_id = ? OR friends_id = ?)', id_left, id_right, id_right, id_left]` but I can not think of method to get friends. I tried this `where: ['user_id = ? OR friends_id = ?', id, id]` but it will only return ids of friends and not friends themselves, so I somehow need to join with User model, but Friendship model has no relation to User model. I'm stuck :(

Comment: did you find a solution ???

Comment: @tetar no, I dropped the project and sequelize as well

Answer (score 0):

You can just override method `hasFriend` with your own logic

```js
        classMethods: {
            associate: function (models) {
            },

        },
        instanceMethods: {
            hasFriend: function (user) {
                // write any logic for check it ....
                return sequelize.models.find({where:{x:y}});
            }
        },
```